# How to call "Action Result" ASP.NET MVC at specific time (Daily)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, actionresult

I have a system for sending E-mails to users by a specific time . 
built in ASP.NET MVC4 and has an action result "function" for checking the time of messages and send it if the day of the message is today .

how can I call this action result (daily) -like a scheduler- in efficient way  ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would definitely create a separate application to send out the emails and set up a scheduled task on the server to run it daily. Setting up timers in a web application like this is risky. If the application isn't accessed for a period of time, IIS could unload it and your daily task along with it.

Comment: If you are not that strict to use MVC action, checkout hangfire.io . It's awesome. http://hangfire.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst a separate service / application would be better, you could use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

> GNU Wget is a free software package for retrieving files using HTTP,
>   HTTPS and FTP, the most widely-used Internet protocols. It is a
>   non-interactive commandline tool, so it may easily be called from
>   scripts, cron jobs, terminals without X-Windows support, etc.

You would then do something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" --no-check-certificate https://www.exammple.com/YouController/YourAction -O NUL
```

in a `.bat` file and set that to run via a windows Scheduled task at the time you require (assuming you don't need to run it less than every 60 seconds - if you do, let me know as I have another way around this using a windows service to call the bat file instead).

Omitting the `-O NUL` part would also save the output so you could see if everything ran successfully by doing:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    //Do your code, get some stats that show it ran properly.
    return Content("Return your stats here.");
}
```

from your controller action.

Comment: what if the time is on day,hour ,and minute , I mean I want to send the email by specific time ,  EX: 26/8/2016 03:44 pm ?

Comment: You can set the scheduled task up to do that. Set it to start at that time and just run every 24 hours. Another thing you could do is add a check in the Action to ensure the time is correct and if not, sleep for a second.

Answer (score 0):

More efficient will be when you create new application as Windows Service. There u can easy set code to start at specific time. in this solution you will have more flexibility and independent. You can start hire : [Windows Service to run a function at specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151363/windows-service-to-run-a-function-at-specified-time)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small console application that just calls the API do send out the emails. You can then schedule the console app to run at a specific time using the Windows Scheduler; you can even have it run without showing the console window. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) or [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx) for details on how to schedule a task.

Answer (score -1):

Use Azure Functions, that's exactly what it was built for. It's really good.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview