# How can I reset the scores of the game on certain days using firebase in "Unity"

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

How can I reset the scores of the game on certain days using firebase in "Unity"

[image]

I want the scores I marked in the picture to be reset every day, every week, at the end of every month, in short, when their time comes. How can I do this?

Comment: You have several options by schedule jobs: [Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151363/windows-service-to-run-a-function-at-specified-time) for free, or paid [Cloud Scheduler](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html) and [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to look into is the [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) feature called [scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

If you're only familiar with Unity, you'll want to follow [this getting started guide for more details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). The basic gist of it is that you'll create a tiny snippet of JavaScript that runs at a fixed schedule and lets you perform some administrative tasks on your database.

I'll try to encapsulate the basic setup:

- install [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- run `npm install -g firebase-tools`
- create a directory where you want to work on functions - you probably want to to do this *outside* of your Unity directory
- run `firebase login` to log in to the Firebase CLI
- run `firebase init` (or `firebase init functions`) and follow the steps in the wizard to create some functions code to test
- when you're ready to use them in your game, you can use `firebase deploy` to send them off to the cloud.

From the [Scheduled functions doc page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), you can see this example of how to run a function every day:

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
  return null;
});
```

You can use these with the [Node Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#node.js). Something like:

```
// Import Admin SDK
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Get a database reference to our blog
var db = admin.database();

exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  db.ref(`users/${user_id}/`).update({userGameScore: 0, userMonthScore: 0, userScore: 0, userWeeklyScore: 0});
  return null;
});
```

Of course, here I'm not iterating over user ids &c.

One final note: this is a very literal interpretation and answer to your question. It may be easier to (and save you some money if your game scales up) to write a score and timestamp (maybe using [ServerValue.Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/server-value)) together into your database and just cause the scores to appear zeroed out as client logic. I would personally first try taking this approach and abandon it if it felt like it was getting too complex.

Comment: thanks for your help but i couldn't fully understand exactly where i should write these codes so i mean the above question automatically reset the score by firebase console on a certain date

I am asking because I do not know if this sample score you gave is reset from within the game or by console as I said.
and sorry for my bad english grammer

Comment: Ok, I made some edits that hopefully make it clearer! Basically the code I provided is JavaScript (rather than C#) that will run on Firebase using a feature called "Cloud Functions". This is a bit of a learning curve, but with "Scheduled Functions" you can run code in the cloud at a fixed interval and by using the Admin SDK you can make that code edit resources in your Firebase project. I hope that clears it up, and if not feel free to keep hashing it out here or reach out to @pux0r3 on Twitter!